# Generate frozen inference graph for older version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to the Tensorflow Models documentation it should be possible to freeze a model for Tensorflow 1.4

> each frozen inference graph can be regenerated using your current version of Tensorflow by re-running the exporter, pointing it at the model directory as well as the corresponding config file in samples/configs.
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

When trying to freeze my model I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 96, in <module>
    from object_detection import exporter
  File "C:\detection\object_detection\exporter.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.quantize.python import graph_matcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'graph_matcher'
```

So is the documentation wrong?